# Looking for working version of tests for final Angular2 Tour of Heroes

Tags: angular

The Angular2 Tour of Heroes tutorial is great! I learned so much by walking through it. However, the tests were not maintained as a part of the tutorial. So now I want to start off with the tour of heroes as a base to build more things, but the tests don't work. I do an "npm run test-once" and I get an error:

```
04 01 2017 14:33:18.385:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome 04 01 2017 14:33:19.764:INFO [Chrome 55.0.2883 (Windows 8.1 0.0.0)]:
Connected o n socket /#xllTF8FZdOEL9EuRAAAA with id 63237867 04 01
2017 14:33:20.314:WARN [web-server]: 404:
/base/node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js Chrome 55.0.2883
(Windows 8.1 0.0.0) ERROR   {
    "originalStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\tError:
XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\tError loading
node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js as \"angular-in-memory-web-api\" from
app/app.com ponent.spec.js",
    "zoneAwareStack": "Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\tError:
XHR  error (404 Not Found) loading
node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js\n\tError loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js as \"angular-in-memory-web-api\" from
app/app.co mponent.spec.js",
    "originalErr": {
      "originalStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js",
      "zoneAwareStack": "Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js"
    }   }
```

a. Is there a simple way to fix this error? 
b. Is there anyone who has made the necessary changes to the Tour of Heroes tutorial to keep the tests running? Seems like a valuable thing that would help the community.

Comment: Don't you want to fix these errors yourself? Seems like a valuable thing that would help you. :)

Comment: @R.Richards Spent some time doing that and was looking for a little help as I'm getting started with it.